# Set definition problem

Tags: article-writing

I want to write in a Proposition:

"There exists $x_1$ and $x_2\geq x_1$ so that
(a) If $x\in [0,x_1)$, then $A>B$.
(b) If $x\in [x_1,x_2)$, then $A\leq B$.
(c) If $x\in [x_2,\infty)$, then $A>B$."

The problem is that each of these sets can be empty based on some other conditions (which are very ugly to write down and I want to avoid that). For the first two making them empty is easy, but for the third I cannot just say $x_2=\infty$ imo. Right?

We now wanted to write:
"There exist potentially empty sets $[0,x_1)$, $[x_1,x_2)$, and $[x_2,\infty)$ so that
(a) If $x\in [0,x_1)$, then $A> B$.
(b) If $x\in [x_1,x_2)$, then $A\leq B$.
(c) If $x\in [x_2,\infty)$, then $A> B$."

But also this seems to not be entirely correct. Right?

Do you have an elegant solution? Or can the third interval be naturally empty?

Comment: Why do you need to point out that the sets are potentially empty? I don’t see the problem here.

Comment: Because otherwise, the reader may think that property C exists for very high x. But that is not necessarily true

Comment: That clarification seems completely unnecessary in this case. If they were more complicated sets, I think your “potentially empty” phrasing would be the best way to say it.

Comment: I now added more info on the property that will hold. I would feel betrayed as a reader if I would believe that the sequence A>B, $A\leq B$, A>B is always there. Although for some "external reasons" $A\leq B$ always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists $0\leq x_1\leq x_2\leq \infty$ such that:

1. If $x\in[0,x_1)$ then $A>B$.
2. If $x\in[x_1, x_2)$ then $A\leq B$.
3. If $x\in[x_2, \infty)$ then $A>B$.

This is enough to make it mathematically correct; if you want to really make the reader pay attention to the fact these sets could be empty (though it is already obvious as is), you can add:

Notice that depending on $x_1$ and $x_2$, one or more of the sets appearing in $(1)-(3)$ above may be empty.

This uses the well known notational device of the [extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line).

---

**Explanation**

We don't have to explicitly rule out the case of empty sets. For instance, if $x_1=x_2$ then the set appearing in $(2)$ is empty, but the statement "if $x\in[x_1,x_2)$ then $A\leq B$" is still correct. Since the set is empty then $x\in[x_1,x_2)$ is false and so the statement is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

---

**Simplification**

Keep in mind that if indeed your three conclusions are $A>B$, $A\leq B$, $A>B$ as you have written, then you are saying that it is always the case that $A>B$ except when $x\in [x_1, x_2)$. If so, then you can make the wording slightly simplified:

There exists $0\leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \infty$ such that $A\leq B$ when $x\in [x_1, x_2)$, and $A>B$ otherwise.

Comment: Hi Snaw, thanks for that answer and I will grant you the 50 units. So the notational device of extending the real numbers allows us to say $x_2=\infty$, which then implies that case c) is empty, right?

Comment: @Paul Yes, exactly. The notation $[\infty, \infty)$ is still uncommon though and if you keep the formulation as in the first part then you might want to add a comment that in case  $x_2=\infty$ we consider the third set empty. I would go with the simplified formulation "$A\leq B$ when $x\in[x_1,x_2)$, and $A>B$ otherwise" which does not require us to talk of $[x_2,\infty)$ explicitly in the first place, so the problem does not arise.